# Generate polygon between other two

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two lake boundary shapefile from two different years. The size of the lake decreased over the years and I would like to generate the boundaries of the years that are between what I have.

To achieve it I need a technique that looks like the following:

[image]

The black and green polygons represents the ones I have. The red is the what I want first, the Letters should indicate, that the red polygon has the same distance from the black and green.
If possible I'd like the solution in ArcMap (I have advance license).

Comment: I would try treating them as contours. For example, give one a value of 0 and the other a value of 1 then what you want is a polygon of the 0.5 contour.

Comment: Similarly to PolyGeo suggestion first step to convert them to lines. Use Euclidean allocation and convert output raster to polygon. Both based on raster, so make sure to use as small cell size as possible

Comment: I think @FelixIP's comment is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I converted Polygons to Lines and merged the 2 outlines into a single layer.
I then split each Outline by quadrant so the Line ends are sort of parallel to each other.
Finally, I ran "Collapse Dual Lines to Centerline". 
It only worked correctly when I selected 2 lines at a time, of the same quadrant, as in the screen shot.
 You may need to cleanup the Centerlines, Integrate, Feature_to_Polygon.

[image]